# batch script to copy most recent file in directory

Tags: batch-file

Hi here is what I need to get accomplished and not sure how. I have a SQL sever that does daily backup of the transaction logs to a local E drive on the sql server. What I need to do is copy the most recent log file from that server to a remote server. Once I get the script to work I will then setup as a schedule task. Can anyone give me advice on how to copy the most recent file to a different server. This will run daily as well so the file name date will change that is why I need the most recent file in the directory where the backup are going.

Answer (score 1):

Use in the batch file these command lines:

```
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "C:\Path To\Source Folder\*" /A-D-H /B /O-D /TW 2^>nul') do copy /B /Y "C:\Path To\Source Folder\%%I" "X:\Path To\Destination Folder\" >nul & goto FileCopied

:FileCopied
rem More commands after copying file with newest last modification date.
```

This code is explained for example at [Get newest file in directory with specific extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36286413/3074564). Command **DIR** excludes here also files with hidden attribute set as command **COPY** does not copy hidden files. The destination folder must already exist.

Enhanced version with real folder paths:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceFolder=E:\MSSQL\Backup\AaaImaging"
set "TargetFolder=\\servername\F\MSSQL\Backup\Pablo"
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%SourceFolder%\*" /A-D-H /B /O-D /TW 2^>nul') do copy /B /Y "%SourceFolder%\%%I" "%TargetFolder%\" >nul & goto FileCopied

:FileCopied
rem More commands after copying file with newest last modification date.
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `copy /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read also the Microsoft documentation page about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) and [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564).