# batch file - nested for loop with wildcards

Tags: loops, for-loop, batch-file, nested, wildcard

I am a batch file noob and while I can get most to work, I am struggling badly with this one.

I am trying to copy the most recent Firefox Bookmark Backup file of all my users and this is what I got so far:

```
@echo OFF
for /f %%a in (' dir /b /ad "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*default-esr*" ') do (
   set "wildcard=%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\%%a\bookmarkbackups"
   for /f %%b in (' dir "%wildcard%\*.jsonlz4" /b /o-d /tw 2^>nul ') do (
      set "newestfile=%%b" & goto foundfile
   )
)
:foundfile
echo %wildcard%\%newestfile%
xcopy "%wildcard%\%newestfile%" "\\<server IP>\copy\%USERNAME%\firefox\bookmarkbackups\" /h /i /k /s /y
```

The first variable "wildcard" returns the expected path, but I cannot seem to get the second variable "newestfile" to return anything.

I've been trying to adapt this topic to fit my needs: [Get newest file in directory with specific extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36284873/get-newest-file-in-directory-with-specific-extension/)

Also, I've read on here that I need to resolve each wildcard separately, which I think I am doing...

I've tried "for /d" but that puts a ' in place of the expected wildcard values.

I am completely lost here, can someone help?

Comment: Beware of the [delayed expansion trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947) `wildcard` is `set` withing the `for...%%a...` loop, so you need to use `delayedexpansion` and `!wildcard!` within the inner `%%b` loop. PS: Read about `call` and `call :foundfile` else you will process only the first one found. You also would need a `goto :eof` before the `:foundfile` label to prevent flow-through when the `for %%a` loop ends.

Comment: The entire batch file can be replaced by `@for /D %%I in ("%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*default-esr*") do @for /F "eol=| delims=" %%J in ('dir "%%I\bookmarkbackups\*.jsonlz4" /A-D /B /O-D 2^>nul') do @md "\\<server IP>\copy\%USERNAME%\firefox\bookmarkbackups" 2>nul & copy "%%I\bookmarkbackups\%%J" "\\<server IP>\copy\%USERNAME%\firefox\bookmarkbackups\" >nul & exit /B` whereby `exit /B` could be also `goto Label` and the next line is `:Label`. That single command line copies also the newest bookmark backup file of default Firefox profile.

Comment: I would use in the batch file `@for /D %%I in ("%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*default-esr*") do @md "\\<server IP>\copy\%USERNAME%\firefox\bookmarkbackups" 2>nul & copy "%%I\places.sqlite" "\\<server IP>\copy\%USERNAME%\firefox\bookmarkbackups\" >nul & exit /B` for copying the file containing the currently active bookmarks than copying the newest bookmark backup file.

Comment: Mofi, thank you so much for your answer.

I am not using the places.sqlite because the current environment is a different version from the new environment and it keeps getting corrupted on launch of Firefox. The bookmarkbackups method works if the new environment doesn't have a places.sqlite so I think it's the better solution for me.